# Running JAR application (Java) within the window of a VB.NET application?

Tags: java, vb.net, mdi

I need to run an external JAR file (which is minecraft) within the window (form) of a VB.NET application, so like having the program in the center and additional text I like around it.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With shell() command and java.exe -jar yourJarPath/file.jar It should works, if my memory of VB is good.

Comment: That would execute the file yes, but it won't show it in the form like an MDI container would